# Spring Boot: Use incoming access token for outgoing requests. (Internally pass access token from RestController to Component.)

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, hexagonal-architecture

I am wondering what is the best way in a Spring Boot application to internally pass an access token from an incoming request through the different layers, before using it in an outgoing request?

The situation is the following: I am developing a *Webapp* (React) and *Service A* (Spring Boot). Authentication is handled using *Keycloak*.

[image]

Depending on the use case *Service A* has to make a request to *Service B* (plain Java). *Service B* is completely outside of my control. All I got from it is an OpenAPI spec for the API. (I can also not change this OpenAPI spec.)

*Service B* must be called with an access token issued to the user that made the original request to *Service A*. (Therefore client credential flow for inter service communication cannot be used.)

The code of *Service A* is organised according to Hexagonal Architecture. The request is received by a controller (which extracts the access token) and than passed to a service which makes a request to *Service B*.

[image]

I cannot call *Service B* from the *Webapp* directly.

Currently I'm using the naive approach to just pass the access token as a method parameter around. But it doesn't feel right to pollute all methods with a parameter that is not related to the business logic of the application.

Is there a better way to internally pass the access token around? Extracting it in the `AccountController` and have access to it in the `AccountAdapterRest`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "incoming" request authorization should be accessible from Spring security-context.

In case of OAuth2, this request is authorized with a Bearer token and the Bearer string is stored in the default `Authentication` implementations (`JwtAuthenticationToken` when using a JWT decoder and `BearerTokenAuthentication` when using introspection).

You can retrieve it from anywhere as follow:

```java
static Optional<JwtAuthenticationToken> getCurrentRequestAuthentication() {
    if(SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication() instanceof JwtAuthenticationToken jwtAuth) {
        return Optional.of(jwtAuth);
    }
    return Optional.empty();
}

static Optional<String> getBearerToken() {
    return getJwtAuthentication().map(JwtAuthenticationToken::getToken).map(Jwt::getTokenValue);
}
```

As a side note, it is not quite recommended anymore to have Javascript based applications be configured as OAuth2 public clients. You should have a look at the BFF pattern where such application never access the tokens: it is secured with session on a middleware on the server which can be configured as a confidential client, retrieve and store tokens in a secured place and replace session cookie with OAuth2 access token before forwarding a request to the resource server(s). I have written a [tutorial on Baeldung with spring-cloud-gateway configured as a BFF](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-cloud-gateway-bff-oauth2).

Comment: Thanks. This in combination with an [ExchangeFilterFunction](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/reactive/function/client/ExchangeFilterFunction.html) to automatically add the token to all outgoing requests, was what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

As access token is not related to the business logic of the application, why not extract it from `SecurityContextHolder` directly when needed ?

I guess it should be simple and fast to extract access token from `SecurityContextHolder`. So instead of passing access token as a param, we can get it from `SecurityContextHolder` in `AccountAdapterRest` directly.